# "Speak of the devil" neutral-sounding synonym for non-person scenario

Tags: idioms, synonyms, idiom-requests

Is there a neutral-sounding (i.e. doesn't mention the devil) synonym for the idiom "[speak of the devil](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjW4YXWw83KAhWHqxoKHa7hAegQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSpeak_of_the_devil&usg=AFQjCNF0iLTOPW3ecIoxjw9lhHOY5YItQQ)"?

The idiom "are your ears burning" or a derivative of that wouldn't be great for this case because it's referring a non-person event that occurred (i.e. which doesn't have ears).

For example, talking about a computer sending an alert about a possible issue, then not getting any alerts for a while, then talking about the alerts the computer had sent in the past and right after that getting another alert.

Comment: Could you give an example of a "non-person scenario" and how this idiom would be used?

Comment: @AndrewLeach For example, talking about a computer sending an alert about a possible issue, then not getting any alerts for a while, then talking about the alerts the computer had sent in the past and right after that getting another alert.

Comment: Well, I'd use "speak of the devil" for that.

Comment: "And, speaking of which..."

Comment: And “*wouldn’t you know it*” it happened right after we got done talking about it.

Comment: Certainly "speak of the devil" can be used for inanimate objects, web pages, etc.  But I don't know of another idiom which is reasonably well known/understood but avoids the use of "devil".

Comment: Good question, although I usually say *Talk of the devil...* .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

speaking of [substitute a noun]. If you are surprised by the arrival of something or someone, regardless of what it is, you may use /speaking of + noun/
"Speaking of planes, look John, there it is".
"Speaking of friends, ours have just arrived."
"Speaking of grammar, I knew there'd be a question about that."

Comment: Good answer. And honorable mention to @user867's comment on the question of "speaking of which" for a more general approach.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, ***As*** *I/you/he/she/we/they* ***were saying...***  or, ***And right on cue...*** .

Comment: "And right on cue..." will work for the traditional "person" scenarios where you want to avoid calling someone the devil!  Thanks, Dan.